# Can't add node to my scene (Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am creating a game using spritekit.

The user controls a paddle that knocks a ball up and down the screen, and each time the ball hits the paddle the score counter increments by one. What I would like to do is add in a second ball to the game when the user's score is equal to 5, but for whatever reason when I try to add the second ball in to the scene, it doesn't get added.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
 {

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody


if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

// if a body in the scene makes contact with the paddle
// shoot the ball back up
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ballCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & paddleCategory) != 0) {
    // move ball up
    [firstBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(arc4random() % 60 + 20, arc4random() % 80 + 50)];

    // increment score
    self.score++;

    // update score
    self.deathLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.score];

    // if the game score is 5, add another ball to the scene
    if (self.score == 5) {
        NSLog(@"test");
        [self addChild:ball2];
        }
    }
}
```

'**ball2**' has already been pre-initialized before attempting to add it to the scene. When running the game and getting a score of 5, the `NSLog` message is being called, but the scene is not adding in another ball. Why is that? Am I missing something completely? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call with action perform selector, for example;

```
-(void)secondBall
{
    SKSpriteNode *secondBall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"secondBall"];
    secondBall.position = yourPosition;
    [self addChild:secondBall];
}

//Your contact
if (self.score == 5) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction performSelector:@selector(secondBall) onTarget:self]];
    }
```